# What's the best way to re-merge the feature branch to master after reverting in GIT

Tags: git

I have a feature branch called **feature**. I merged it to the **master** but then realize it's not ready to release yet, so I have to revert it to avoid blocking work of other people.

Note that I don't have permission to revert directly on **master**. To revert, I have to create a new branch **feature_revert** from **master**, revert the merge and merge this new branch to **master** again.

Now after a while and my changes are ready to merge again, what's the correct way to re-merge to **master**?

1. Simply merge the **feature** branch to master again. Since I didn't revert directly on master, will Git be able to merge this or it will still recornize this branch as already merged?
2. Revert the revert on **feature_revert** and merge it back to master
3. Create a different branch **feature_remerge**, merge the change from **feature** to this new branch and merge this new branch to master

Sorry if I make things a bit complicated. Just want to know what's the best practice in this situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix a Git master branch after accidently merging the wrong branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307602/how-to-fix-a-git-master-branch-after-accidently-merging-the-wrong-branch)

Comment: git doesn't care, or even know, if something happened "directly on master" or on a branch that was merged in: master's history is every commit reachable by following parent pointers, including both sides of any merge commits.

Answer (score 1):

> Simply merge the feature branch to master again.

That should not work indeed, since it was already merged as part of a PR.

Creating a new separate branch (option 3: `feature_remerge`) is the easiest way to proceed, in order for the right merge content to be merged to `master`.