# My changes are deleted during merge with master after revert

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I have merged a development branch into master. But it was discovered the merge introduced bugs to master, so I reverted my commit. I have fixed the bugs, but when I try to pull from master into my branch, I see that this will delete many of my changes as Git probably determines master to be more up-to-date than some files on my branch due to revert.

How can I merge **all** my work, including both bug fixes and other content without losing anything?

Ideally, I would like to tell git to treat my branch as the newest content because no new commits to master were made since my revert.

To clarify: my original merge included modifications to existing files and some new files. When a bug was found, I've reverted everything. The fix affected only several lines of code. Now, when I try to create a merge request or just pull from master, Git recognizes only these fixes as new content which should be merged, and everything else as old content which should be deleted.

Comment: *How can I merge all my work* You cannot. You must revert the revert on master first. See [this answer and a possible workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54308775/6868543).

Comment: If the *only* commits on `master` are the merge of `development` and then the revert of that merge, then the "state" of `master` is the same as before the merge, making the total of those commits a "wash". If this all happened quickly and others aren't using the latest `master`, you could consider a hard reset of `master` to before the merge. Then you'd be able to re-merge as normal. But if you suspect others are already using the latest `master`, go with @j6t's comment and revert the revert.

Comment: Side note: `development` sounds like a long-lived shared branch, and if it is do not rebase that branch just so you can re-merge.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74642046/341994

Comment: I just realized I misread the question. It says "**a** development branch" rather than "**the** `development` branch". Is that branch a shared branch or just a feature branch with a small number of commits that were reverted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [normal consequence](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) of reverting a merge commit. So, for example, suppose we have this:

```
A -- B -- C <- main
 \
  --- X -- Y <- feature
```

We now merge `feature` into `main`:

```
A -- B -- C -- M <- main
 \           /
  --- X -- Y <- feature
```

We now revert the merge:

```
A -- B -- C -- M -- Mrevert <- main
 \           /
  --- X -- Y <- feature
```

We then continue working on `feature`:

```
A -- B -- C -- M -- Mrevert <- main
 \           /
  --- X -- Y -- Z <- feature
```

We now attempt to merge `feature` into `main` again and we are horrified to discover that most of it is not arriving into `main`! What's happening?

What's happening is that for all the commits that were already merged (X and Y in the diagram), the merge train has *left the station*.  The `revert` has reverted the *state* of `main` but the *topology* of `main` is unaffected; thanks to the merge, X and Y are now on `main`. Those commits have thus *already* been merged into `main` and they can *never be merged again*.

Solution — well, there are a number of ways around this situation. The easiest is probably to make a whole new branch off of `main` at the same point where `feature` branched off it, and `git cherry-pick` the commits of `feature` onto it:

```
A -- B -- C -- M -- Mrevert <- main
 \           /
  --- X -- Y -- Z <- feature
   \
    --- Xnew -- Ynew -- Znew <- featureNew
```

The commits `Xnew`, `Ynew`, and `Znew` will *look* like X, Y, and Z, but they are *different* commits and so they *can* be merged into `main`. Thus, merging `featureNew` into `main` will now have the desired effect.